# What's the difference between 'instance member' and 'property'?

Tags: swift, properties, instance

I ran into an issue " Cannot use instance member'XXX' within property initializer,property initializers run before 'self' is available "
Can you tell me what's this talking about and what's the difference between 'instance member' and 'property' ? I even thought they were exactly the same! Isn't 'instance' just like a 'class',and isn't its member a property?

Comment: I don't think the linked dupe targets completely answer the question – an instance member is simply something that's available to call on an *instance* of a type. This could be an instance property or method. *Static* properties and methods are *not* instance members, as they're called on a type, rather than an instance of a type.

Comment: Hi,Mr.Hamish,as for  " Cannot use instance member'XXX' within property initializer,property initializers run before 'self' is available " ,can I put it this way "Before the whole class is even made,  I am absolutely NOT allowed to use the property of this class to initiate another property" ?

Comment: Basically, yes – you cannot refer to `self` (and therefore any instance members, as they're called on `self`) *before* `self` is fully initialised (i.e before the instance of the class is fully created).